# I am training to invoke dataform from cloud composer. but i want to invoke only ["daily"] sqlx files

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, dataform

I am using bellow Operator but getting error

```
ERROR - Failed to execute job 4338 for task create_workflow_invocation (Protocol message WorkflowInvocation has no "invocationConfig" field.; 385)
```

```
    create_workflow_invocation = DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator(
        task_id='create_workflow_invocation',
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        repository_id=REPOSITORY_ID,
        workflow_invocation={
            "compilation_result": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_compilation_result')['name'] }}",
            "invocationConfig": { "includedTags": ["daily"], "transitiveDependenciesIncluded": true }
        },
    )
```

want to invoke only daily tagged dataform files from airflow

Answer (score 0):

Use the below syntax to call the dataform tags or dependencies

"invocation_config": { "included_tags": ["daily"], "transitive_dependencies_included": true }